# Laravel 4 model unit test with Codeception - Class 'Eloquent' not found

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4, eloquent, codeception

I'm trying to use [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) to run my [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/) unit tests.

Running a test for a simple class with no dependencies works fine. But when I instantiate a model which depends on Eloquent, I get this fatal error:

**PHP Fatal error: Class 'Eloquent' not found in /var/www/project/app/models/Role.php on line 4**

**Unit test:**

```
<?php
use Codeception\Util\Stub;
class TestModel extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test 
{
  public function testExample()
  {
    $role = new Role;
    $role->name = 'superuser';
    $this->assertEquals('superuser', $role->name);
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class Role extends Eloquent
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
  }
}
```

**Project structure:**

I'm running *vendor/bin/codecept run unit* from the project root, with this file structure:

```
/project
  codeception.yml
  /vendor/bin/codecept
  /app
    /tests
      unit.suite.yml
      /unit
         ExampleTest.php
    /models
       Role.php
                ...etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont know about codeception especially, but with PHPUnit, you need to at least [bootstrap the class autoloading](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/phpunit.xml#L4). Perhaps it's the same with Codeception.

Comment: I know this is crazy late but after you install the composer package. You type in the root directory of the site. "vendor/bin/codecept _bootstrap" and that will generate the file for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By looking at the [Codeception L4 sample app](https://github.com/Codeception/sample-l4-app/blob/master/tests/_bootstrap.php), I was able to see how to bootstrap the autoload to resolve this issue, by adding these lines to **project/app/tests/_boostrap.php**:

```
include __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
\Codeception\Util\Autoload::registerSuffix('Page', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'_pages');
```

**Edit:** when upgrading from Laravel 4.0 to 4.1, it is also necessary to add an extra line:

```
$app->boot();
```

Comment: be careful with include PATH !

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably late to the party, but if you don't need the codecept stuff. You should be extending laravel's implementation of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase called just TestCase. Like this:

```
class TestModel extends TestCase {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is a little outdated now. With **Laravel 5** I got the same error (*Class 'Eloquent' not found...*) and solved it by copying the code from Laravels base [TestCase.php file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php). This file is used for testing within the Laravel framework (NOT using codeception).

To fix the 'Eloquent not found' error, add the following lines to **project/tests/unit/_bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
$app = require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
```

Honestly I'm not sure why it works, but it does! I'll edit if I figure out why or someone comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `Eloquent` class cannot be found when you are running your unit tests.

Try adding `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;` to `Role.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to TestCase class and override method refreshApplication (add method to TestCase) with adding auth or some:

```
protected function refreshApplication()
{
    $this->app = $this->createApplication();

    $this->client = $this->createClient();

    $this->app->setRequestForConsoleEnvironment();

    $this->app->boot();

    // authenticate your user here, when app is ready
    $user = new User(array('username' => 'John', 'password' => 'test'));
    $this->be($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with Laravel 4 and Codeception by adding the following lines to `_bootstrap.php`

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot();`

Hope this helps a fellow googler!